# How to get the Count of a column which has different values in it

Tags: mysql, sql

| agent-name | position | qa_agent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | fatal | admin |
| Second | non fatal | admin |
| Second | non fatal | admin |

**I need a output like this**

| agent-name | Count of qa agent | Count Fatal count | Count Non fatal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Second | 1 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `conditional aggregation`

```
select agent_name,
       count(distinct qa_agent) as Count_qa_agent,
       count(case when position='fatal' then 1 end) as Count_fatal,
       count(case when position='non fatal' then 1 end) as Count_Non_fatal
from tablename
group by agent_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Fahmi's answer is fine.  But MySQL allows a more concise version:

```
select agent_name,
       count(distinct qa_agent) as Count_qa_agent,
       sum(position = 'fatal') as Count_fatal,
       sum(position = 'non fatal') as Count_Non_fatal
from tablename
group by agent_name;
```

That is, you can add up boolean expressions without having to use explicit conditional logic, because `1` is equivalent to "true" and `0` is equivalent to "false".